# How to split authors?

Tags: posts, split

I have 3 authors, each of us talk about the same subject but in a different mind/opinion. I want to have 3 pages for each of us and show ONLY the posts for each author one them.

Like have a page called AuthorOne that has only the first authors posts, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don’t you use the author archive?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the Template hierarchy, then you'll notice that there're actual author archives:

> Archive Page: `author-{$nicename}.php` >> `author-{$id}.php` >> `author.php`

This means, that you can simply add an `author.php` file to your theme and style it whatever you want. The **Loop** will give you all posts by this author. If you want to style them differently per author, then use `author-{$nicename}.php` template files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, `query_posts('author=' ID OF THE DESIRED AUTHOR)` is what you are looking for.

An example:

```
query_posts('author=' ID OF THE DESIRED AUTHOR);
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    DO YOUR STUFF
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

**// Edit**

You can, of course, incorporate a certain category or some other filter argument into your query.

Link to the Codex for [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Comment: Please don't use `query_posts()`. It's a bad advice, as it overwrites the main query object.

Comment: @kaiser - Hm, `it's a bad advice` doesn't read that nice, in my opinion. Of course, using the author archive is a good (most probably even 'better') way. However, the question was about THE listing of posts on THE page, so I thought it legitimate to assume it would be THE (main) query. And if not, I included the link to the codex (for caveats and drawbacks etc.) and I also included `wp_reset_query` in my example.

Comment: @kaiser I agree with @t f. _I want to have 3 *pages* for each of us_ There is no 'main query' on a page. If you want to display e.g. post from a single category, then yo have to use `wp_query`

Comment: @Ralf912 - there's a main query on *every* WordPress page, in the case of the `page` post type, it's that page's data.

Comment: @tf `query_posts` should never be used, period. if it's a modification of the main query, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), if it's an additional query (as in your example), use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: @Milo The query is already done when the page is displayed, you can't 'destroy' it with `query_posts()`. Kaiser talks about the query inside the loop (e.g. front page). If you do a `query_posts()` inside the loop, you get troubled. On a plain page, there is no loop until you create one.

Comment: @Ralf912 - you are mistaken. there is a main query on every page/post type, including `page`. when you load posts via `query_posts` on a page, you overwrite the page's query. the [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) conditional will return false when it should be true. if you have code which relies on knowing the context of the main query, it will produce unexpected results. there is no reason to ever use `query_posts`, `WP_Query` will achieve the same results without overwriting the main query.

Comment: @Ralf912 In addition to what **Milo** already wrote: The problem is the reference between `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` and `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`, which will break.

Comment: @Milo & @kaiser [This](https://gist.github.com/RalfAlbert/5091600) is my testcase. The `is_page()` condition returns true as expected and the "main query" is still untouched. You can test it with `$old_query = $wp_query` and after `query_posts()` compare both `var_dump( $old_query === $wp_query )`

Comment: @Ralf912 well yes, because you've restored the original query. but if there was a filter on loop_start, loop_end, the_title, etc., for example, that code would produce unexpected results.